# API data won't convert to JSON format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

Had the data in JSON in a previous build of my app but (with the help of StackOverflow community) redesigned how I call my API to fix various other breaking errors.

This is what I just tried. I log both the "regular" output and the attempt at converting it to JSON. The non-json output comes up as "{data: Array}" in my console while the JSON is undefined.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "API_KEY"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data
        const json = data.json
        this.setState({ data, loading: false });
        console.log(json);
        console.log(data)
      });
  }
```

And here is my other attempt:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("API_KEY").then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      this.setState({ data, loading: false });
      console.log(data);
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
      
    });
  }
```

All your help and advice is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: If `data` is an array, why do you expect `data.json` to exist? `json` isn't a property found on arrays.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert to JSON anyway? Generally APIs provide data **as** JSON, and then `axios` parses it into a useful JavaScript data format for you automatically.

Comment: Can you provide an example output of your API call? Your second attempt seems pretty fine to me.

Comment: I wish I could go back in time and delete w3schools. Jesus Christ. This is going to haunt people forever. `const json = data.json` is nonsense. Your `res.data` is an object (the already parsed by axios JSON from the server). You don't need anything else.

Comment: @ChrisG — I've been wanting to go back in time and delete w3schools for almost 20 years. <sigh>

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, their most cursed page `https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp` is still online, still talking of "JSON objects"... :/

Comment: Object
data: Array(6)
0:
availability: "internal"
body: "TEST"
date_created: "2022-01-07"
date_updated: "2022-01-10"
id: 9
posted_by: "Finn Jefferis"
sort: null
status: "published"
title: "Test"

This is an expected output. @TheOrigin

Comment: .........I used that exact page. I'm assuming w3schools isn't a resource being recommended?

Comment: W3Schools is awful. Riddled with errors, half truths, and examples of code with massive security holes in them. MDN is a better default.

Comment: @Quentin Only trying to convert to JSON as I could easily display the desired API data when it was in JSON format and now everytime I try I get the "reading properties of undefined" error.

Comment: JSON is a text format. The server uses it to transmit the data. axios then parses this text into an object and provides it to you as `res.data`. To access any of it's properties, you can simply do `console.log(res.data.whatever)`. Turning it back into JSON is nonsense; you only think you have to do that first because w3schools grossly mislead you about what JSON is. To access the properties, you need an object, and `res.data` is *already* the object you need.

Comment: Here's a short explanation with example code: https://jsfiddle.net/wqng0hLb/

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a better syntax using ES6.

```
  const componentDidMount = async () => {
    let { data } = await axios.get("API_KEY")
    
    // Your data by default should be object or array.
    // Regardless, both should worked fine.
    console.log(data)
    
    // In case it is just string and not undefined
    if (data && typeof data !== 'object') {
        data = JSON.parse(data)
    }

    this.setState({ data, loading: false })
  }
```

Otherwise, try using breakpoint or console.log in the first place after getting the result. If the result is undefined, perhaps the promise is yet to resolve.

Comment: Note: your object is always pass by reference, better to console.log in the first place to avoid the other function mutating your object. This will avoid confusing or mutated object.